# .Net SQL Server DDL API

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ddl

Does there exist a .Net (C#) API for SQL Server DDL operations? Here are some examples of the type of code I might want want to write...

Instead of...

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE [a_new_db];", sqlConnection))
{
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'd rather write...

```
MyAwesomeApi.CreateDb("a_new_db");
```

Instead of...

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [a_group] ADD DATABASE [a_new_db];", sqlConnection))
{
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'd rather write...

```
MyAwesomeApi.JoinToAvailabilityGroup("a_group", "a_new_db");
```

Comment: What you're looking for is an ORM. There are many ORM's out there that allow you to create DB's and Schemas using a fluent coding approach. Here's one that I contribute to. [AppCore.Data](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/AppCore.Data), and [here's the Wiki](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/AppCore.Data/wiki/Creating-a-Migration) on creating databases.

Comment: Chase, thanks for your comment! How does AppCore.Data differ from the SQL Server Management Objects solution that Mike lists in his answer below?

Comment: it generates the DDL based on the Dialect it's using. We use it to enable identical db schemas across multiple platforms (MS Server, iOS, Android). It's also just a specific "flavor" of fluent coding. We like the way the API reads. It is however very opinionated, so it's important to follow some of the opinions if you intend on using it fully.

Comment: also available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FutureState.AppCore.Data/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql Server Management Objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx